# Spring state-machine pooling error

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have implemented Spring statemachine in UML and am trying to implement a connection pool. 
my configuration class is

```
@Configuration
public class CambodiaStateMachine {


 @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Bean
public StateMachineListener<String, String> listener() {
    return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
            System.out.println("State change to " + to.getId());
        }
    };
}

@Bean(name = "stateMachineTarget")
@Scope(scopeName="prototype")
public StateMachine<String, String> stateMachineTarget() throws Exception {

    Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.<String, String>builder();

    builder.configureConfiguration()
    .withConfiguration()
    .machineId("cambodia")
    .autoStartup(true);


    builder.configureModel().withModel().factory(modelFactory());
    builder.configureConfiguration().withConfiguration().beanFactory(appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    return builder.build();
}

@Bean
public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
    return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:stm/model.uml");
}


@Bean
public CommonsPool2TargetSource poolTargetSource() {
    CommonsPool2TargetSource pool = new CommonsPool2TargetSource();
    pool.setMaxSize(10);
    pool.setTargetBeanName("stateMachineTarget");
    return pool;
}

 @Bean
 @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public ProxyFactoryBean stateMachine() {
        ProxyFactoryBean pfb = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        pfb.setTargetSource(poolTargetSource());
        return pfb;
    }
```

}

and I'm getting an error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create scoped proxy
>   for bean 'scopedTarget.stateMachine': Target type could not be
>   determined at the time of proxy creation

.
NOw I tried playing with it and removed

> proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

the error was no more but the intended behavior was not observed. There was no pool but just one machine running.

I have seen this bug [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/283) but saw no solution.

Comment: Btw could you mark your questions answered if you think those are answered ;)

Comment: Sorry I just checked. It worked!! Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue linked to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15042. Check Spring framework version as there were regression as this works with 4.3.3 and 4.3.6 but not with 4.3.4, 4.3.5.

Comment: I no more get the error but still sometimes the same state machine instance works for simultaneous requests. why is this?

Comment: Probably because requests are not simultaneous. You'd see errors if you launch multiple threads and smoke test like that.

Comment: No i dont use threads but I use a message Queue. So as soon as I feed the State Machine, the next request comes along before the machine goes back to the pool. So it clashes there. Is there anything I can do about it? like a way to know if there's an active SM at the moment?

Comment: I dont think that the above is correct, according to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-scopes beyond the default (singleton) scope only session scope is allowed.